# Applying a function to a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I can't figure out why this isn't working.  I have a data set with 5 columns, n rows.  I just want to apply a function to each row and have the result returned in an n by 1 vector.

Just to test out how everything works, i made this simple function:

```
f1 <- function(uniqueid,Perspvalue,expvalue,stddevi,stddevc) {
    uniqueid+ Perspvalue- expvalue+ stddevi+stddevc
}
```

and here's the first few rows of my data set:

```
> data
     uniqueid   Perspvalue    expvalue      stddevi      stddevc
1           1 2.404421e+03  3337239.00 8.266566e+03 3.324624e+03
2           2 1.345307e+03  3276559.87 7.068823e+03 2.648072e+03
3           3 1.345307e+03  3276559.87 7.068823e+03 2.648072e+03
```

Note that it's a data frame (i think), and not a matrix.  I loaded in the data from a csv using read.csv.

So i try this: `apply(data,1,f1)`

But my result is this: `Error in uniqueid + Perspvalue : 'Perspvalue' is missing`

I expected a number instead of an error.

Comment: In addition to @PaulHiemstra's approach, you could also just do `apply(data, 1, function(row) row['uniqueid'] + row['Perspvalue'] - row['expvalue'] + row['stddevi'] + row['stddevc']`. Apply sends a named vector, so you can use those in the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use `mapply` for this, or even more convienient `mdply` from the plyr package.

Some example code:

```
spam_function = function(a, b) {
  return(a*b)
}

require(plyr)
input_args = data.frame(a = runif(1000), b = runif(1000))
result = mdply(input_args, spam_function)
> head(result)
           a         b         V1
1 0.46902575 0.6865863 0.32202668
2 0.56837805 0.2400993 0.13646717
3 0.07185661 0.2334754 0.01677675
4 0.15589191 0.6636891 0.10346377
5 0.98317092 0.8895609 0.87459042
6 0.46070479 0.4301685 0.19818071
```

If you just want the vector of results:

```
result_vector = result$V1
```

Or alternatively, a base R solution using `mapply`:

```
result_mapply = mapply(spam_function, a = input_args$a, b = input_args$b)
> head(result_mapply)
[1] 0.2757767 0.1268879 0.5851026 0.7904186
[5] 0.2186079 0.1091692
```

Comment: When using mapply, i now get this error:

`Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'mydata' of mode 'function' was not found`

Comment: Then use `mdply`, and I can't read minds, so if you want feedback please post the exact code that produced the error. I added an example using `mapply` which runs fine.

Comment: Ah, okay i got mapply working now.  I was just using it incorrectly.  mdply looks very nice, but i'm not able to load packages on my work computer, unfortunately.  Thanks for the examples. I think i'll be okay from here on!

Comment: @tkrex Are you serious? Why can't you load packages on your work computer? They deliberately stop you, or you just didn't figure out --internet2 startup option?

Comment: Some IT departments are very restrictive, requiring every bit of software to be certified, even an R package.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I get an authentication error when i try to install packages using the dropdown in R.  I found out i can do it though, if i download the zip file and install that way.  Haven't yet had time to check out mdply, though.  Thanks for all the help.